# How to get values of fields of List<of_anonymous_type> (plus casting)?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, casting, mstest, anonymous-types

I have this code. At the very end we have `List` of anonymous objects with fields `FILE_NAME`, `DATE`, `REPORT_LINK`.

```
public ServiceResult Get(string userIdString)
{
    var userId = Int32.Parse(userIdString);
    var downloadLink = _serviceConfigManager.Parameters[ServiceResources.DownloadService].FirstOrDefault();
    var query = SharedUnitOfWork.Context.ReportRequest
        .Where(item => item.IS_DELETED == 0
                    && item.TENANT_ID == TenantId
                    && item.REPORT_STATE_ID == 2
                    && item.CREATED_BY_USER_ID == userId)
        .OrderByDescending(item => item.ID)
        .Take(10)
        .ToList()
        .Select(item => new
            {
                FILE_NAME = item.FILENAME,
                DATE = item.CREATION_DATE,
                REPORT_LINK = string.Format("{0}/{1}", downloadLink, item.ID)
            }
        );
    return new ServiceResult<object>(query.ToList());
}
```

First of all as you can see we return `ServiceResult<object>` object.
The second, the returning type of function is `ServiceResult` (NOT GENERIC).
This code i didnt write SO I CANT CHANGE THE SOURCE CODE of this method.

The task:
In my unit tests i need to get returning object and check if it is populated with correct data. 
I wrote my test the way the function `Get` returns 2 records. 
SO, i need to check every field in this records. How to do that?

In my tests i get from this function variable of `serviceResult` name.
How to "unwrap" `serviceResult` so as it looks like a `List<of_something>` and I could check `List<of_something>[0].FILE_NAME`, `List<of_something>[1].FILE_NAME` and etc?

`serviceResult` has `Result` field that equals `query.ToList()`.

**TO MODERATORS**: I read all offered similar topics, non of them describes|solves my task because I can't rewrite source code of Get function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved using Reflection.

Using pattern `targetType.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName).GetValue(targetType,index:optional)`
I can get value of any field of anonymous type.

In case of indexer I use `GetProperty("Item")` and `GetValue(targetType,new object[]{0})`, where the second parameter is needed index.

Answer (score 4):

You can't get hold of the anonymous type. Your options are:

- use reflection (`GetType().GetProperty()` etc) to read the data
- use `dynamic`

The latter is probably more convenient:

```
foreach(dynamic obj in listOfAnonObjects) {
    string filename = obj.FILE_NAME;
    DateTime date = obj.DATE;
    string link = obj.REPORT_LINK;

    // TODO: now use filename, date and link
}
```

You could use the above to project the data into your *own* list type that has well advertised properties.

Comment: Thank you for your thoughts.This is the great solution but i have another problem. I get ServiceResult instead of ServiceResult<List<of_items>>. So, somehow i need to get (ServiceResult<List<of_items>>).Result first of all. And then i can enumerate Result field. ServiceResult has only 3 fields: State,Entity,Message, and ServiceResult<T> has Result which i need to get needed info.

Comment: @Adventurer and what is `.Result`? what type is it? is that the list? if so: that's where `listOfAnonObjects` comes in

Comment: Yes, .Result is a list of anonymous objects. But .Result contains in ServiceResult<List<of_anon_obj>> and not in ServiceResult that i get from the function. Thus i have no access to the field .Result until i cast somehow ServiceResult to ServiceResult<List<of_anon_obj>>.

Comment: @Adventurer are you sure it isn't a `List<object>`? You can't send a `List<{anon type}>` in a public method signature...

Comment: List<T> is type of .Result field

Comment: Try just using dynamic for this as well, or reflection. `((dynamic)result).Result` should allow you to use the list, and then you need to use `dynamic` for each element of the list to get hold of the elements. Then finally, have a good talking to with the person who wrote that method.